# What happens to injected javascript when new page is loaded in android webview?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

What happens to injected javascript when new page is loaded in android webview (using loadurl)? Does it gets cleared or is it still effective on the new page? Is it dependent on if new page was loaded programmatically or by clicking on the links in html page? If javascript does remains in the webview after new page is loaded, how do you clear it? Does injecting same javascript after every page load make webview glitchy and unresponsive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading a new page into WebView clears all the previous web contents and scripts, regardless of their source, and regardless of the way you have loaded the new page (that is, by navigating from the page's side, or by using WebView's Java API).

What gets reinserted is injected Java objects (added via `WebView.addJavascriptInterface()`), although their JavaScript counterparts are recreated from scratch. That means, if you have added custom properties or methods to injected objects on the JavaScript side, they will be gone.

Regarding the last question -- that largely depends on the nature and size of the JavaScript code you are injecting. If the script is not huge, and doesn't do a lot of stuff, then injecting it should happen fast enough and not affect page responsiveness.